# How to run WinRAR on Ubuntu (the original Windows WinRAR, not UnRAR)?

Tags: 16.04, windows, wine, zip, rar

How to run WinRAR on Ubuntu (the original Windows WinRAR, not UnRAR)?

Can you do it with Wine somehow? I think I tried that with 14.04 but failed, maybe it's possible with 16.04 or should be possible in 18.04?

I desire to work with WinRAR regularly, to extract zips and rars after a **right mouse click** and "unrar this file to / here" or "unzip this file to / here".

In an answer, please detail on a workaround to achieve that (as working with WinRAR that way, is actually part of the problem).

Comment: The right click functionality won't work properly; this is because of the limitations of the difference between Windows and LInux context menus.  BUt it *does* look like you can run [WinRAR within Wine](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=391) though I don't have any statistics about whether the versions in the Ubuntu Repos of Wine will work well or not.

Comment: First getting into Wine, then unrar/unzip with WinRAR? Oh that sounds quite depressing. Is there no good way to make it more comfortable? Some "wine-application" shortcut from somewhere?

Comment: I don't know enough about the context menus in the right-click menu because of the varying file explorers in the individual desktop environments to give you a clear answer or not.  Ideally though you could extract zips and rars *already* by installing the `unrar` tool and `unzip` tool from the repos, which adds support with the built-in tools.  There's really no need for WinRAR directly, though, what with the opensource tools that exist now for it... just saying.

Comment: When i right-click on a rar file, i get 2 options, `Extract here` and `Extract to`. If you don't get it, you may want to install 7zip-full with `sudo apt-get install p7zip-full` and test later.

Comment: @bistoco I didn't understand, that's after you installed **WinRAR** on Wine? Or you don't work with WinRAR at all?

Comment: @user9303970 He didn't use WinRAR at all, he used `p7zip-full` which is Open Source, and got RAR files to extract without issue.

Comment: @user9303970, @ThomasWard is correct, i gave you the behavior of `7zip` package.
**Opinion**: even when wine provides some compatibility with windows software on linux, it's always better to move away from them using native software, usually better (with exceptions) and with less issues.